# How to make scanning DB rows in Go DRY?

Tags: database, go

I have a table in the database containing user account information. I have a struct called User defined.

```
type User struct {
  Id        uint
  Username  string
  Password  string
  FirstName string
  LastName  string
  Address1  string
  Address2  string
  .... a bunch more fields ...
}
```

For fetching individual user accounts, I have a method defined

```
func (user *User) GetById(db *sql.DB, id uint) error {
  query := `SELECT 
            ...a whole bunch of SQL ...
            WHERE id = $1
            ... more SQL ...
            LIMIT 1`
  row := db.QueryRow(query, id)
  err := row.Scan(
    &user.Id,
    &user.UserName,
    &user.Password,
    &user.FirstName,
    &user.LastName,
    ... some 20 more lines of fields read into the struct ...
  )
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return nil
}
```

And there are several places in the system where I need to fetch user information as part of a larger query. That is, I am fetching some other type of object, but also a user account related to it.

That means, I have to repeat the whole `rows.Scan(&user.Username, &user...)` thing over and over again and it takes a whole page and it is error prone and if I ever change the user table structure I would have to change the code in a whole bunch of places. How can I make this more DRY?

Edit: I am not sure why this was marked as a duplicate, but since this edit is required, I will try to explain one more time. I am not asking how to scan a row into a struct. I already know how to do that, as the code above clearly shows. I am asking how to structure the struct scanning code in such a way that I do not have to repeat the same page of scanning code every time I am scanning the same type of struct.

Edit: also, yes, I am aware of sqlstruct and sqlx and similar libraries. I am deliberately avoiding these, because they depend on reflect package with well documented performance issues. And I intend to potentially scan millions of rows using these techniques (not millions of users, but this question extends to other record types).

Edit: so, yes, I know I should write a function. I am not sure what this function should take as arguments and what results it should return. Lets say that the other query I want to accommodate looks like this

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.name,
    ... more site fields ...
    u.id,
    u.username,
    ... more user fields ...
FROM site AS s
JOIN user AS u ON (u.id = s.user_id)
JOIN some_other_table AS st1 ON (site.id = st1.site_id)
... more SQL ...
```

And I have a site struct method that embeds a user struct. I don't want to repeat the user scanning code here. I want to call a function that will scan the user portion of the raw into a user struct the same way it does in the user method above.

Comment: nice outcome https://play.golang.org/p/eI4kFrPWLb1

Comment: One comment is that the sql library itself also uses reflection for all attributes that are not strings, []byte, time.Time and a couple others ([here is the function that does the scanning process](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.6:src/database/sql/convert.go;l=220)). So not using reflection isn't really an option. I also did a few [benchmarks](https://github.com/vingarcia/ksql#benchmark-comparison) comparing using libs with structscan and libs without it, the time is pretty much the same because the bottleneck is the network latency, not the reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate the repetition of the required steps to scan the `*sql.Rows` structure you could introduce two interfaces. One that describes the already implemented behaviour of `*sql.Rows` and `*sql.Row`.

```
// This interface is already implemented by *sql.Rows and *sql.Row.
type Row interface {
    Scan(...interface{}) error
}
```

And another one that abstracts away the actual scanning step of the row(s).

```
// have your entity types implement this one
type RowScanner interface {
    ScanRow(Row) error
}
```

An example implementation of the RowScanner interface could look like this:

```
type User struct {
    Id       uint
    Username string
    // ...
}

// Implements RowScanner
func (u *User) ScanRow(r Row) error {
    return r.Scan(
        &u.Id,
        &u.Username,
        // ...
    )
}

type UserList struct {
    Items []*User
}

// Implements RowScanner
func (list *UserList) ScanRow(r Row) error {
    u := new(User)
    if err := u.ScanRow(r); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    list.Items = append(list.Items, u)
    return nil
}
```

With these interfaces you can now dry your rows-scanning code for all of your types that implement the RowScanner interface by using these two functions.

```
func queryRows(query string, rs RowScanner, params ...interface{}) error {
    rows, err := db.Query(query, params...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rs.ScanRow(rows); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return rows.Err()
}

func queryRow(query string, rs RowScanner, params ...interface{}) error {
    return rs.ScanRow(db.QueryRow(query, params...))
}

// example
ulist := new(UserList)
if err := queryRows(queryString, ulist, arg1, arg2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// or
u := new(User)
if err := queryRow(queryString, u, arg1, arg2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

---

If you have composite types that you want to scan but you want to avoid having to repeat the enumeration of its elements' fields, then you could introduce a method that returns a type's fields and reuse that method where you need it. For example:

```
func (u *User) ScannableFields() []interface{} {
    return []interface{}{
        &u.Id,
        &u.Username,
        // ...
    }
}

func (u *User) ScanRow(r Row) error {
    return r.Scan(u.ScannableFields()...)
}

// your other entity type
type Site struct {
    Id   uint
    Name string
    // ...
}

func (s *Site) ScannableFields() []interface{} {
    return []interface{}{
        &p.Id,
        &p.Name,
        // ...
    }
}

// Implements RowScanner
func (s *Site) ScanRow(r Row) error {
    return r.Scan(s.ScannableFields()...)
}

// your composite
type UserWithSite struct {
    User *User
    Site *Site
}

// Implements RowScanner
func (u *UserWithSite) ScanRow(r Row) error {
    u.User = new(User)
    u.Site = new(Site)
    fields := append(u.User.ScannableFields(), u.Site.ScannableFields()...)
    return r.Scan(fields...)
}

// retrieve from db
u := new(UserWithSite)
if err := queryRow(queryString, u, arg1, arg2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Seems like I need two separate methods for Row and Rows, since these are different types. Otherwise, this is a good way of abstracting away row scanning. Thanks.

Comment: @MadWombat I'm not sure what you mean by two separate methods. And by "Row and Rows" you mean *sql.Row and *sql.Rows?

Comment: Yes, so in the interface I guess I need to implement ScanRow(row sql.Row) and ScanRows(rows sql.Rows) to accommodate results from both Query and QueryRow

Comment: No you don't need to, if you define the interface that's at the top of my answer (`type Row interface {`), which is implemented by both `*sql.Row` and `*sql.Rows` out of the box, you can use that as the argument to ScanRow, i.e. `ScanRow(r Row) error`. Try it out, you'll see that when you pass *sql.Row and *sql.Rows to ScanRow your program will compiler just fine. Remember that in Go interfaces are satisfied implicitly which means that you can define interfaces for types that already exist without modifying them.

Comment: Ah! I see. Thank you.